# Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular JS for the first time.

Here is my code and its not working. typeahead intellisense is showing as 'Unknown attribute'.

```
 <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="HomeController">
    <h4>Search State</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
</div>

function HomeController($scope, $http) {
$scope.selected = undefined;
$scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
}
```

Am I missing some JS files ?

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle

Comment: What is your `$viewValue` variable set to? Is it present in your `$scope`? You should not use names starting with the `$` symbol for variables as a best practice.

Comment: Can you show all your code with the application modules and html please.

Comment: @jpmorin see the below answer, that is my code.

Comment: @jpmorin I found that the same code working fine in Web forms but not in MVC. What would be the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see working example here http://plnkr.co/edit/SjASFL8BkKdjLRxUlGVA?p=preview

make sure that you've got those scripts

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
```

and you definition of your app include ui.bootstrap

```
var app= angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: I opened your link and its says example.js. What is that ? If I remove that example.js, it is not working.

Comment: I haven't understand that part. where to add var app= angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']); ? what is the app code ?

Comment: Its not working for me. why typehead attribute is showing as unknown attribute in VS 2013 ?

Comment: @user3757426 you can use data- ie: data-typeahead' please see here not best approach but everything on one page http://plnkr.co/edit/SjASFL8BkKdjLRxUlGVA?p=preview

Comment: Please read the angular documentation as stated by @sss to know how an angular project works. You must include the `angular` and `ui-bootstrap` scripts before your own modules to make it work.

Comment: @jpmorin The only thing I did not understand is example.js. I want to know how exactly it got generated and the code that js file contains.

Comment: @jpmorin What do you mean by it is not used here ? I take out that example.js file in plnkr link and it is not working.

Comment: @user3757426 have you seen that example .. ? dont miss <body ng-app="app">

Comment: @sss I found that it is working fine in Web application but not in MVC. what would be the issue ?

Comment: @user3757426 http://plnkr.co/edit/20q22JnVxqMuOXFy215T?p=preview copy and paste that into your _Layout.cshtml page